# What if the owner remove address A from whitelist?

Tags: contract-development, tokens, erc-20, openzeppelin

Let's imagine account A has the 1000 tokens and it's in the whitelist. Since this token provides the functionality of removing someone from the whitelist only to the owner. What if remove account A from the whitelist.

**My question is what will happen to his/her tokens? Tokens will be discarded? OR Account A will be able to transfer token when he/she whitelisted again?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The concept of whitelisting is something that is custom-built. Yes, there exist some templates for the functionality, but in the end it simply depends on how you implement it.

If you add whitelisting to token transfers, then the token can't be transferred unless you are in the whitelist. The tokens don't disappear anywhere, they appear in the user's wallet normally, but they are basically rendered useless (unless his ability to transfer them is restored).